# how to retrieve date stored in the sqlite and converte it to timeStamp to be able to compare it with the current date?

Tags: android, date, error-handling, android-sqlite

i have an android application that use sqlite database and stored date under field name **"match_date"** in this format **2014-06-12**.

what i want is to retrieve the stored dates then convert it to time Stamp to be able to compare it with the current date.

## this is the chunk of code

```
public Cursor getAllRows(PendingIntent notificationIntent) throws ParseException {
        String where = null;

        c = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();

            // test for get current date and convert it to timeStamp 



            Log.e("time test","the current date in timeStamp =" + d1.getTime());



             int index = c.getColumnIndex("match_date");


             Date dateInGetAllRow = (Date)format.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date")));


            Log.e("inside the getAllRows", "first day is " + dateInGetAllRow.getTime());



            Log.e("inside the Shownotification", "index is" + index);


            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                listdetail = new ItemDetails();

                listdetail.setTeam1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team1")));

                listdetail.setTeam2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team2")));

                listdetail.setDate_match(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndex("match_date")));








                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    Notification notification = builder
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fifa_2014_4)
                            .setContentTitle("Up Comming Match")
                            .setContentText(
                                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team1"))
                                            + (c.getColumnIndex("team2"))).build();


                    displayNotification(notification);




                c.moveToNext();
        }


      }
        return c;
    }
```

hope that someone can help me i will appreciate this help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not not sure you mean this:

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
Timestamp ts = Timestamp(date.getTime());
```